# React Native - Why we use the tintColor property for Image component?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, tintcolor

When i use `tintColor` property it fills the whole image to the color i specified to the `tintColor` property. Is i am using it wrong or its job is the same what i get? Can anyone tell for what purpose this property is used for `<Image/>` component and what is the proper use of this property? A little example will be more appreciated. Thanks !!!

[Reference link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image-style-props#tintcolor)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the documentation, `tintColor` changes the color of all the non-transparent pixels to the tintColor (taken word for word).

So for example, in one of my React Native packages, I use have an increment asset - https://github.com/hannigand/react-native-ui-stepper/blob/master/assets/increment.png - which has a blue + sign. Using `tintColor`, another User can recolour the blue (non-transparent pixel) to any colour they desire.

Comment: Transparent pixels are those which don't have anything to show. and non-transparent pixels are those which has something to show. For example the dots in this picture are the non-transparent pixels and area other than the dots is transparent pixels in this link: http://sadinthecity.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/polka-dot-background-.png. Is i am correct?

Answer (score 14):

```
<Image
  tintColor='#2d3436'
  style={{width: 20, height: 15,margin:10}}
  source={{uri: 'backsignup'}}
/>
```

This works fine for android but not in ios

If you want it to work on ios as well go with this ie. passing tint color with style instead of passing it as a props

```
<Image
 style={{ width: 20,height: 23,margin: 10,tintColor: "#2d3436"}}
 source={{ uri: "pdficon" }}                                                 
/>
```

Answer (score 12):

Using `tintColor` in `<Image>` is not working.

Using it in the `style` of `<Image>` works.

Ref: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17124

Comment: Indeed, using as a style works for sure. That's a bug but maybe it's the answer for his question, since the way that he uses does not work.

Answer (score 5):

I think this will clear out your confusion for tintColor property of Image.

React Native Styling Cheat Sheet - https://github.com/vhpoet/react-native-styling-cheat-sheet#image

[image]

[image]